# Broken screen & disabled display in Acer v5 series Windows 8 PC

Tags: windows-8, graphics-card, acer-aspire, intel-core-i5

I really need help. I was so stupid and I only had one Intel graphics card. I disabled it in my [Acer Aspire v5 laptop](https://www.acer.com/ac/en/LA/content/series/aspirev5), not knowing it would not function without it.

The problem is when I turn on my laptop, the screen is on but it's so shattered and broken so it's connected to my TV and when I start the laptop it doesn't show on the TV, so I can't reset anything.

I've been searching th web and watching videos to find an answer. I've taken out the battery and took everything plugged away. I've turned the laptop on and off and I still don't know what to do.

Is there a way to enable my Intel graphics and get the laptop displaying on my TV screen?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can!

You disabled the video card in Windows 8, but you can use another Operating System, different from Windows, to use the PC, such as a [LiveUSB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Live_USB) made with [Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux). Linux is free (as in beer) and will not cost you anything.

The following steps will not erase or change anything saved on the internal drive of the PC. All your pictures, messages, music, and movies saved in the Acer will still be there.

Get a USB flash memory drive, 4GB or larger, typically under $10 at Target, Kroger, or Wal-Mart, or wherever you like. Bigger can be useful for other uses, but not necessary here. If you have one you can reuse it, but this will erase what's on it.

Download the free Open Source Ubuntu Linux 20.04 ISO file from https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop to a different PC.

Download the free Open Source program, [Rufus](https://rufus.ie), from  https://github.com/pbatard/rufus/releases/download/v3.10/rufus-3.10p.exe which does not need to be 'installed' to the Windows PC you are using to work.

Start the Rufus program and make a Linux LiveUSB following these instructions https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows

Once make, eject the USB flash drive and plug it in to your [Acer v5](https://www.cnet.com/reviews/acer-aspire-v5-review/) PC. Power up and when you get to the Boot Menu, choose the USB flash drive to boot from. The Ubuntu Linux operating system, with a functional set of programs preinstalled, will load, so you can use your PC.

Linux is Windows-like, but different here and there; it uses different programs, although some programs (like the [Firefox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firefox) and [Google Chrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome) web browsers) work in both Windows and Linux. Your library will have many books on [Ubuntu Linux](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B004Y1NMDI), and [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lmeDvSgN6zY) has many videos for it.

If you like it and want to have it permanently, you can [choose to install Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop) on your Acer laptop, without deleting your Windows 8 and its data. There are also other 'flavours' of Ubuntu with the same functionality, but different 'desktops', you can get for free from https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours explained [here](https://itsfoss.com/which-ubuntu-install/) and [there](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuFlavors).

There's even a Q&A site, like this site, but dedicated to Ubuntu, where you can ask questions and get answers, https://askubuntu.com

I hope this works for you and will be here to answer questions.

Comment: This is one of the best, patient, loving, involved answers I have ever seen in the interwebs.

Answer (score 1):

There's a way to get into Windows 8 while bypassing its current settings. It's called **Safe Mode** and is designed for when there's a problem with Windows settings.

if you press and hold down the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key while tapping the <kbd>F8</kbd> key, you will be able to access the Advanced Boot options. Note that this may need a few tries.

[image: Windows Safe Mode screen]

Try Safe Mode with Networking, or Low Resolution Mode.

If neither works, try the other answer I have below.